Error: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity during OIDC when a PR get merged into main
I'm trying to assume a role of AWS using OIDC in my github action file but it's saying "Error: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity" When we merge PR into main but if I change the setting to work on push into main then it works. I'm sharing the whole use case below.
In my AWS I have added my identity provider with the following settings
provider name : token.actions.githubusercontent.com
audience : sts.amazonaws.com
In my Roles, I've following trust policy added
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::5599526xxxxx:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": [
                        "repo:organisation-name/repo:ref:refs/heads/main",
                        "repo:organisation-name/repo:pull_request"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

In the permission section, I've added 1 custom permission as well which I'm attaching
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Following is the Github Action File
name: Deploy to Amazon ECS
on:
  pull_request:  #If I change setting for push it will work but on this setting it throws the error
    branches:
      - main
    types:
      - closed
env:
  AWS_REGION: us-east-1              
            
permissions:
      id-token: write   # This is required for requesting the JWT
      contents: read    # This is required for actions/checkout
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: sandbox
    steps:
      - name: Git clone the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: configure aws credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::5599526xxxxx:role/github-role
          role-session-name: samplerolesession
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}   
          

Does anybody can suggest what is possibly wrong here?

Add this step to generate OIDC token explicitly and examine the OIDC token for claims on jwt.io. Full workflow:
name: id-token

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  get-id-token:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
    steps:
      - run: |
          ID_TOKEN=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer $ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" "$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL&audience=api://demo" | jq -r .value)
          echo $ID_TOKEN | base64

You will need to base64 decode the token before viewing it on jwt.io.
When I merged a PR, I saw
"sub": "repo:owner-name/repo-name:pull_request"

What do you see?

env.ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL and env.ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN are null so it didn't do anything

Updated my answer - the values are already set as environment variables, no need to inject them

It shows me the right sub data, which is "sub": "repo: organization-name/repo-name:pull_request" but I still can't log in via OIDC. it's giving the same error Error: Could not assume role with OIDC: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

Have you tried just using aws CLI to call STS to assume role? Perhaps, you will get better error information. You already have a token.

It's showing the following error in CLI "An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Incorrect token audience" In your above response I updated the audience with "https://sts.amazonaws.com" but still it's giving the same error in CLI

Hi @delta, it finally worked!! When I decoded the JWT token then I realized there was 1 small issue with the trust policy, in my test project it was working fine but in my actual file it was changing the sub like this
repo:owner/repo:environment:sandbox
So when I added this as a sub, it started working, so the thing that worked was decoding the JWT token. So anybody who faces such an issue he needs to decode that token and match the sub and if it's different as compared to AWS trust policy then it should be made the same and everything will work fine

What defines ‘sandbox’?

sorry for the delayed response but I updated the GitHub action file in the question and it was like
deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
environment: sandbox

I had this issue and that solved it for me as well. Getting the JWT token and pasting exactly the sub in there into my aws trust policy for the role
